# fullcalendar qtip2 eventClick (for edit)

Tags: fullcalendar, qtip2

I was able to create a qtip2 on dayClick (fullcalendar) and it saves data for that event. Now I am trying to click on the event to have qtip2 load up again, but nothing happens. I have set editable to false (otherwise eventClick would never work).

I would like to be able to re-open a qtip2 event so it can be edited....thanks in advance

(NOTE: the DayClick qtip2 works great)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here

            aspectRatio: 1.3,    

            editable: false,
            draggable: true,                
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            unselectAuto: false,
            disableResizing:true,

            header: {                    
                right: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
            },

            events: "json_events.php",                                              


            eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {

                //alert(event.title);       

                $(this).qtip({    
                    content: {    
                        title: { text: event.title },
                        text: "<span class='title'>Start: </span>" + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'hh:mmtt')) + "<br><span class='title'>Description: </span>" + event.description + "<br /><input type='button' value='Update' class='button' />"   
                    },
                    position: {
                        at: 'top center',
                        // Position the tooltip above the link
                        my: 'bottom center',
                        adjust: {
                            y: -2,
                            resize: false // We'll handle it manually
                        },
                        viewport: calendar,
                        container: calendar
                    },
                    show: {
                        solo: true
                    },                         
                    style: { 
                        width: 200,
                        padding: 5,
                        color: 'black',
                        textAlign: 'left',
                        border: {
                            width: 1,
                            radius: 3
                        },
                        tip: 'bottom-middle',
                        classes: 'daytooltip ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow',
                        tip: {
                            width: 20, height: 8
                        }                        
                    } 
                });     //element.qtip                    

            },

            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) { 
                   var month=new Array();
                    month[0]="January";
                    month[1]="February";
                    month[2]="March";
                    month[3]="April";
                    month[4]="May";
                    month[5]="June";
                    month[6]="July";
                    month[7]="August";
                    month[8]="September";
                    month[9]="October";
                    month[10]="November";
                    month[11]="December"; 

                   var monthNum=new Array();
                    monthNum[0]="01";
                    monthNum[1]="02";
                    monthNum[2]="03";
                    monthNum[3]="04";
                    monthNum[4]="05";
                    monthNum[5]="06";
                    monthNum[6]="07";
                    monthNum[7]="08";
                    monthNum[8]="09";
                    monthNum[9]="10";
                    monthNum[10]="11";
                    monthNum[11]="12";  

                    var allday = "<label for='allday'><input type='checkbox' id='allday' onClick='enabledisable(this.checked)' /><span>All Day Event</span></label>"
                    var thisDay = month[date.getMonth()] + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                    var thisDayDBFormat = date.getFullYear() + '-' + monthNum[date.getMonth()] + '-' + date.getDate();

                    var sHours = "<select id='startTimeHour' name='startTimeHour' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +                                                               
                                    "<option value='01'>01</option>" +
                                    "<option value='02'>02</option>" +
                                    "<option value='03'>03</option>" +                        
                                    "<option value='04'>04</option>" +
                                    "<option value='05'>05</option>" +
                                    "<option value='06' selected>06</option>" +
                                    "<option value='07'>07</option>" +                        
                                    "<option value='08'>08</option>" +
                                    "<option value='09'>09</option>" +
                                    "<option value='10'>10</option>" +
                                    "<option value='11'>11</option>" +                        
                                    "<option value='12'>12</option>" +                                       
                                    "</select>";
                    var sMins = "<select id='startTimeMin' name='startTimeMin' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +
                                    "<option value='00' selected>00</option>" +
                                    "<option value='15'>15</option>" +
                                    "<option value='30'>30</option>" +
                                    "<option value='45'>45</option>" + 
                                    "</select>";                              
                    var sAM_PM = "<select id='startTimeAMPM' name='startTimeAMPM' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +
                                    "<option value='AM'>AM</option>" +
                                    "<option value='PM' selected>PM</option>" +                                        
                                    "</select>";                                                    

                    var eHours = "<select id='endTimeHour' name='endTimeHour' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +                                        
                                    "<option value='01'>01</option>" +
                                    "<option value='02'>02</option>" +
                                    "<option value='03'>03</option>" +
                                    "<option value='04'>04</option>" +
                                    "<option value='05'>05</option>" +
                                    "<option value='06'>06</option>" +
                                    "<option value='07' selected>07</option>" +
                                    "<option value='08'>08</option>" +
                                    "<option value='09'>09</option>" +
                                    "<option value='10'>10</option>" +
                                    "<option value='11'>11</option>" +   
                                    "<option value='12'>12</option>" +                                        
                                    "</select>";
                     var eMins = "<select id='endTimeMin' name='endTimeMin' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +
                                    "<option value='00' selected>00</option>" +
                                    "<option value='15'>15</option>" +
                                    "<option value='30'>30</option>" +
                                    "<option value='45'>45</option>" + 
                                    "</select>";                              
                    var eAM_PM = "<select id='endTimeAMPM' name='endTimeAMPM' class='dropdown-menu-time-qtip' >" +
                                    "<option value='AM'>AM</option>" +
                                    "<option value='PM' selected>PM</option>" +                                        
                                    "</select>";                          

                    $(this).qtip({
                    overwrite: true,
                    content: {                            
                        title: {
                            text: 'Create Event / Add Menu Item: ', // + month[date.getMonth()] + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear(),
                            button: true
                        },
                        //text: $('#fxx').html() // this html was on the form

                        //text: "<span id='event-create' ><ul><li><input type='checkbox' />All Day</li><li><input type='radio' />input:radio</li><li><select><option>Select</option><option>Foo</option><option>Bar</option></select></li><li></li><li><input type='text' value=" + month[date.getMonth()] + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + "/></li><li><textarea>textarea</textarea></li></ul><input type='button' class='button' value='Create Event' /></span>"
                        text: "<div id='event-create'>" +                                
                                "<fieldset>" +
                                    "Create a Generic Event OR add a Menu (meal) Event from your Personal Menu!" +
                                    "<br />" +
                                    "<label>When:</label><span>" + thisDay + "</span>" +
                                    "<br />" +                                        
                                    "<form action='.' method='post' name='create_event'>" +
                                        "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='save_event' />" +
                                        "<input type='hidden' name='eventDate' value='" + thisDayDBFormat + "' />" +
                                        "<label for='eventName'>Name:</label><input type='text' name='eventName' value='' title='Letters, numbers, and underscore!' size='30' />" +
                                        "<br />" +
                                        "<label for='eventLocation'>Location:</label><input type='text' name='eventLocation' value='' title='Letters, numbers, and underscore!' size='30' />" +                                                                                                                                   
                                        "<div id='event-create-time'>" +
                                            "<input type='checkbox' name='eventAllDay' onClick='enabledisable(this.checked)' /><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;All Day Event</span><br />" +
                                            "Start: " + sHours + " " + sMins + " " + sAM_PM + "<br />" +
                                            "End:&nbsp;&nbsp;" + eHours + " " + eMins + " " + eAM_PM + 
                                        "</div>" +
                                        "<br />" +
                                        "<input type='submit' id='event-button' name='btnSaveGenericEvent' class='button150' value='Create Generic Event' />" +                                                                                    
                                        "<input type='submit' id='event-button' name='btnSaveMenuEvent' class='button150' value='Create Menu Event' />" +                                         
                                    "</form>" + 
                                "</fieldset>" +
                            "</div>"
                            //"<a href='#' onclick=" + '"' + "document['my_personal_menu'].submit()" + '"' + " >My Personal Menu >></a>" +
                    },
                    position: {
                        at: 'top center',
                        // Position the tooltip above the link
                        my: 'bottom center',
                        adjust: {
                            y: -2,
                            resize: false // We'll handle it manually
                        },
                        viewport: calendar,
                        container: calendar
                    },

                    // NOTE: originally, tooltip opened as modal (gray background) and had to close with 'x' button
                    // Settings were "show: Modal: on: true AND hide: 'false'
                    //
                    // To have tooltip popup on each day click AND have any previous tooltip go away (like google calendar)
                    // Settings "show: modal: on: false AND hide: 'true'"
                    show: {
                        ready: true,
                        event: false,
                        modal: {
                            // 'true' = Make it modal (darken the rest of the page)...
                            on: false,                                
                            blur: false // ... but don't close the tooltip when clicked
                        }
                    },
                    // 'false' = does not hide when clicking outside
                    // 'unfocus' = will hide when clicking outside tooltip IF modal 'on: false' (above)
                    hide: 'unfocus',
                    style: {
                        classes: 'daytooltip ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-default width400',
                        tip: { width: 20, height: 8 }                                                 
                    }
                })
                .qtip('show');
            }
```

Comment: Ah ha, I am not sure what I did but I was able to get this working!! I changed some of the settings and wa-la....

Comment: Have you posted your working solution??

Comment: Please post working solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution from Craig:

Try attaching a qTip with `overwrite` set to `false`, and update its content at the end of the call:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        $(this).qTip({
           overwrite: false,
           content: 'Loading...',
           show: { ready: true }
        })
        .qtip('option', 'content.text', newContent);
    }
});
```